# Aero borders cut off space from my WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, aero

Unfortunately I can't provide screenshots for comparison now, since I'm unable to use Aero here at work, but I'm having the following problem:

I'm creating a small WPF application. My main window is not resizable, and the sizes and positions of everything inside are fixed. Everything works fine here using some pre-defined theme (it's "Windows Classic" most likely). Once I run the exe at home though - with Aero enabled - the border size is way bigger, but the actual total window size stays the same it seems to me. So the borders go "into" my window, shrinking the actual usable space and thus some of my controls are overlapped by the borders and it looks asymmetrical.

What can I do about this, if anything? Is there some option to make the borders be attached "outside" my used window space?

**Edit:** Here is an uploaded image of the Aero version. I hope the problem can be seen. (It's at the bottom) [image: Aero borders]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a static size is a bad way in wpf.

There are different solutions:
1. make your window a bit heigher or 
2. reduce the margin between your used content elements or
2. use a dynamic size of your content. A grid with rowdefinitions set to "X*" where x is the height in propotion to total height of your content.

But im not sure ... you use a style in your app or is the style directly set into element? If you use a xaml stysle file, is it possible the style overrides your set position or margin properties?

Comment: Hey! Yes, in the meantime I have switched to using a dynamic size as you say. But the thing is: I don't use any style here whatsoever, not even a small adaption of a single component. It's just a fixed-size window with content created using absolute coordinates. This above behavior just doesn't feel 'right'.